# how to make UIBarButtonItem send new address to UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uibarbuttonitem

I have a uiwebview embedded within a navigation controller. I would like the ability to change the uiwebview by simply clicking a uibarbuttonitem. anyone have any idea how to do that?

heres the method i have right now.

```
-(void)action {

    if (item.link) {
        self.linkString = item.link;
    }
    NSString *urlAddress = @"%@/#comments", linkString;

    NSURL *address = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:address];
    [contentLabel loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the target selector or IBAction to change the request object:

```
  -(IBAction) action {
         NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";

         NSURL *address = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
         NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:address];
         [theWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
```

or

```
  -(void) action {
         NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";

         NSURL *address = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
         NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:address];
         [theWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
```

Comment: ok that works perfectly. now what if i wanted to make the url change?

like if i want it to have the same url as the webview but with /#comments tacked on at the end?

Comment: Do you mean go to a specific anchor?

Comment: what i have right now is

if (item.link) {
  self.linkString = item.link;
 }
 NSString *urlAddress = @"%@/#comments", linkString;

but it doesnt like the NSString *urlAdd... line

Comment: NSString *anchor = @"#y-footer";
 
 NSURL *footertag = [NSURL URLWithString:anchor];
 NSURLRequest *scroll = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:footertag];
 [webView loadRequest:scroll];

(I believe in a different selector this would work.)

Comment: wait, so i need to make another method with that in it? and what is the #y-footer?

Comment: the first one you said worked. just had to add: 

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/#comments", linkString];

to it

Comment: Okay!  I just had typed it in to the browser so I was a little unsure.